# How can I identify a user without login feature in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm making Django app where visitors can answer to questions without login feature. The number of each answer will be counted as 'votes', but I need to restrict a user to answer a question only once.

I need someone's help who has experienced in this.

Comment: check ip of user, or save a cookie in user's browser

Comment: Please add some code and we'll see if we can get to a specific solution. Django sessions is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Django Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) or try to hack together something on your own using [metadata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) from each request.

### Django Sessions

> Django provides full support for anonymous sessions. The session
>   framework lets you store and retrieve arbitrary data on a
>   per-site-visitor basis. It stores data on the server side and
>   abstracts the sending and receiving of cookies. Cookies contain a
>   session ID – not the data itself (unless you’re using the cookie based
>   backend).

### Request META data

In every request in Django it carries around something called `META` which carries metadata about the request. Depending on how you use Django views (function-based views or Class Based Views) you will access `META` a little differently.

The request object in Django is a key-value store, or basically a dictionary. So in a function based view you'd use. If you're looking to track IP addresses then you can use `REMOTE_ADDR` inside of `META`. However, this is not foolproof as users may use VPNs to browse with a different IP address.

#### Function based view

```
def my_view(request):
    ip_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    # do your stuff
```

#### Class Based View

```
class MyClass(TemplateView):

    def get_context_data(self):
        ip_address = self.request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        # do your stuff
        context['ip_address'] = ip_address
```

From there you might want to provide more specifics for what you're trying to do. But you should be able to use some combination of the data in the request `META` object to track your users and provide them a better experience.

Answer (score 1):

by IP is one way to go though most users IP will change at some point. You can have you front-end forward the networking mac address which is much more unlikely to change. You can also give each person when they visit a non-expiring cookie to hold their session, though these can be deleted by the user and won't be there if they swap browsers.

An OR between Mac address, cookie, and IP is your best bet. Record all 3 and if they visit and any of those match then assume it's the same person

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this example by [simpleisbetterthancomplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com) which explain a very good [this example](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/02/03/how-to-use-restful-apis-with-django.html#basic-example-geo-location-api) on you query regard. You can use the user ip and compare it every time when the use upload the answer and then restrict the user according to your need. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

storing a token in the user browser may achieve this.
I had done this some years ago but storing other relative data will prove the accuracy of unique users (like token + IP).

```
seen = objects.browser_seen.filter(token=token, news__id=object_id).exists()
if not seen:
    obj = BrowserSeen.objects.create(token=token)
    obj.news_set.add(objects)
```

if a token does not exist, a random token is set to the response.